# Why are most unanswered questions about technology?

Tags: discussion

Basically, I noticed that almost all of the questions on the "unanswered" tab are about technology in some way or another. Does this come as a consequence of a lack of experts in that field on our site? Is this a problem?

Comment: Why certain questions remain unanswered, and certainly whether that is a problem, is a largely speculative question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It looks like most of the unanswered questions that are about technology are about **DJ** technology, and there aren't a lot of DJs on here.
- Some of the questions are about obsolete and/or unpopular technology that not as many people will be familiar with.
- Some of the questions are unclear, and it often takes a lot of accurate details to answer a technology question.
- Music.SE is really a site for musicians, many/most of whom do use some amount of technology, but are not primarily technology-focused people.